# Nginx doesn't server subfolder api application (php-fpm)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, xubuntu

I have following folder structure for my application, located in map `/home/valor/development/mypp.com/public_html/`

```
- css
- app
- js
- ...
- server (codeigniter)
  -- system
  -- application
  -- index.php
- index.html (angularJS app)
```

this is my nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html;

        index index.html;

        server_name euro-swap.com www.euro-swap.com;

        location / {
              index  index.html;
        }

        location /server/ {
                index /server/index.php;
                try_files $uri /server/index.php/$uri;
        }

        location /twitter/ {
                index /twitter/index.php;
                try_files $uri /twitter/index.php/$uri;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }

        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
        }
}
```

And this is the error i'm keep getting

```
2016/03/04 18:26:02 [error] 4577#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/valor/development/myapp.com/public_html/server/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /server/api/users/isLoggedIn HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "http://myapp.com/"
2016/03/04 18:26:02 [error] 4577#0: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/valor/development/myapp.com/public_html/server/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /server/api/categories HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "http://myapp.com/"
2016/03/04 18:26:03 [error] 4577#0: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/valor/development/myapp.com/public_html/server/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /server/api/products/latest/16 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "http://myapp.com/"
```

Page is displayed correctly i just can reach api resources in sub folder.
Can you guy help me out what i'm doing wrong?
If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be a permission problem, possibly caused by AppArmor. Please review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295466/3699457) to see possible solution. I don't want to steal the answer, therefore linking to it.

EDIT: the problem might now occur from the php-fpm configuration. Please open `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` with your favorite editor and uncomment the following lines:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

and don't forget to restart the php server with:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: now i have another problem
"/var/www/html/myapp.com/public_html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied),
I added 644 premision on files and 755 premison on folders, also i have change ownership to www-data, etc

Comment: edited my answer. now we see that it can connect but nginx / upstream receives a permission denied as lack of rights. the edit in my answer should solve it.